# whitespace padding a file length using echo in a windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, text-formatting, echo

I'm using a for loop in a windows .bat file to make a text-file listing files in directories.

`FOR /R %%G in (*) DO (

  ECHO %%~zG      %%~nxG >> zzz-list.txt

)`

[Phone won't let me input a tab character; the whitespace between ~z and ~nx is 6 spaces, one tab]

Output is similar to (again, no tab):

```
134      zzz-list.txt
16931      Other-file
3249237       anotherfile
269164509       thirdfile
```

I'd like it to be (for human readability):

```
      134
    16931
  3249237
269164509
```

I need to put ~z into a variable, test the length and then forward pad it with the correct number of spaces.  Ideally the script would go thru all the files looking for largest size, and set that as the length to pad to, but I might be happy just hard coding that length to a reasonably large size.  (Ie: several extra spaces at the beginning of every line is not a deal-breaker).

I'm having trouble setting and displaying variables, much less running operations on them.

Tried:

`SET _var1=%%~nxG

ECHO %_var1%`

With and without quote marks, and it wasn't working for me.

Comment: Prepend with spaces and use [substrings](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) `Set "_var1=            %%~zG"` and `Echo !_var1:~-12! %%~nxG` requires a prior `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` when used in a (code block)

Comment: Thanks for the link @LotPings, that solved my next problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of prepending white space to a string, and then showing the rightmost 12 characters:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%N in (1 12 123 1234 12345 123456 1234567 12345678) do (
    set numberstring=                %%N
    echo !numberstring:~-12!
    )
```

output was:

```
       1
      12
     123
    1234
   12345
  123456
 1234567
12345678
```